# Indefinite symmetric quadratic form with inequality constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, constraints

I have a scalar quantity $\Phi =u^TAu$ that I am tracking as part of a greater optimization problem.
$A=I-(1+\mu^2)nn^T$, where $u$ is a 3 x 1 vector, $I$ is the 3 x 3 identity matrix, $\mu$ is a non-negative scalar, and $n$ is a normalized 3 x 1 vector ($n^Tn=1$). The eigenvalues of $A$ are $(1,1,-\mu^2)$. Therefore, $A$ is an indefinite, symmetric matrix. Everything is real-valued.

I wish to constrain my choice of $u$ such that $\Phi\leq0$. Because $A$ is indefinite, this condition is dependent on $u$. How can I enforce this constraint? I was hoping there was a way to define a matrix $X$ such that $u=Xv$, to transform this into an unconstrained optimization problem (similar to a subspace method) but I will appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Comment: Oh! Good catch. Everything else seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you project $u$ onto the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $1$, the feasible region is a circle whose radius depends on the remaining component of $u$. So, you can either solve a problem with a quadratic constraint, or do a polar transformation.

An eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $-\mu^2$ is $n$. You can write $u = Xw$ where $X$ is $3 \times 3$ whose first column is $n$ and the other two columns an orthogonal basis for the space orthogonal to $n$, and $w$ is $3 \times 1$.

The condition $u^TAu \leq 0$ is equivalent with $w_2^2 + w_3^2 \leq w_1^2 \mu^2$. Writing $w_1 = r \cos \theta$ and $w_2 = r \sin \theta$, this becomes $0 \leq r \leq w_1 \mu$.

So now we have three options:

1. use $u^T A u \leq 0$ as a constraint
2. use $w_2^2 + w_3^2 \leq w_1^2 \mu^2$ and $u = Xw$ as constraints
3. reformulate the entire problem with polar coordinates and add the linear constraint $0 \leq r \leq w_1 \mu$

The constraint $w_2^2 + w_3^2 \leq w_1^2 \mu^2$ is convex (second order cone) only if $w_1 \geq 0$ or if $w_1 \leq 0$, but not for $w_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. So, if you can solve two constrained convex optimization problems (one for $w_1 \geq 0$, one for $w_1 \leq 0$), option 2 probably has the best numerical performance.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in accepting this answer. I basically didn't understand anything you were saying until recently. In my case, the condition $w_1<=0$ is guaranteed, so despite the indefinite matrix, the constraint is convex. So, my objective function is convex, and all my constraints are convex. That led me to try the log barrier method and it works great!

Comment: @CharlieS glad to hear, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\mu^2}}=\cos\phi$ where $\phi\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Then $\mathbf u^TA\mathbf u\le0$ if and only if $\mathbf u=0$ or $\left|\left\langle\frac{\mathbf u}{\|\mathbf u\|},\mathbf n\right\rangle\right|\ge\cos\phi$. Therefore
$$
\mathbf u=x\left(\cos(\theta)\mathbf n+\sin(\theta)\mathbf t\right)
$$
for some $\theta\in[-\phi,\phi]$ and some unit vector $\mathbf t\perp\mathbf n$. Let $P\in\mathbb R^{3\times2}$ be any matrix whose two columns together with $\mathbf n$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Then we can write
$$
\mathbf u=x\left(
\cos\left(\phi\cos\alpha\right)\mathbf n
+\sin\left(\phi\cos\alpha\right)P\pmatrix{\cos\beta\\ \sin\beta}
\right)
$$
where $x,\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unconstrained.